# CSS triangles all across the width of browser

Tags: html, css

Imagine we have a triangle:

```css
article {
  position: relative;
}

article>.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</article>
```

Is it possible to change css to achieve many triangles, which are all across the width of a browser?

Comment: Are you only allowed to use CSS? Does the triangle have to be made from CSS? Or can you use an image? @jakub1998

Comment: This seems like using a hammer to screw in a lightbulb. Why not use an image (perhaps using SVG)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this and pick whatever color you want the triangles to be:

EDIT: Shortened thanks to Temani Afi's comment.

```css
.triangle {
  height: 30px;
  background-image: 
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #FF0000 0), 
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #FF0000 0);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</article>
```

Comment: I would add `background-position: 15px 0;` to have a full a triangle at the start

Comment: Ahh thank you I didn't even notice the first one was cut in half.

Comment: more shorter :p